# rethinkdb - how to do nest `group` query

Tags: rethinkdb

My document

```
{
  itemName: 'name1',
  itemType: 'book',
  createTime: '2014-09-24 10:10:10'
 }
```

Then I want to query the last `n` days  created item group by `createTime` and `itemType`

In other words, I expected my result something like this

```
[{
  group: '2014-09-24',
  reduction {
      {
        group: 'book', 
        reduction: {count: 100}
      },
       {
        group: 'computer',
        reduction: {count: 100}
      },
  },
  {
  group: '2014-09-22',
  reduction {
      {
        group: 'book',
        reduction: {count: 100}
      },
       {
        group: 'computer',
       reduction: {count: 100}
      }
  }
}]
```

The rql may looks like

```
r.db(xx).table(yy)
 .order({index: r.desc(createTime)})
 .group(r.row('createTime').date())
 .map(function() {
  ????
}).ungroup()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also directly order everything (but you don't get nested fields:

```
 r.db(xx).table(yy)
   .group([r.row("createTime"), r.row("itemType")])
   .count()
```

You somehow cannot use `group` inside `group` for now.
See https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/3097 to track progress on this limitation.